# how to search any number exits in a list using python

Tags: python, paramiko

I am trying to search any IP in a list. 
Below is the list of string, from this list i want to search for if any IP exist using python.

```
[
   'Neighbour', 
   'Information:', 
   'Chassis', 
   'type', 
   ':', 
   'Mac', 
   'address', 
   'address'
   ' :'
   '146.89.4.32'
]
```

Comment: Where is number in above list? Can you please share another example.

Comment: It can be anything. Which I am not aware.

Comment: what if integer present,  edit question with whats your expected output

Comment: All I want to know is, is there any number exits in the list if not exits then break.

Comment: alright, if integer present then it will be 10.0.4.3, for an example

Comment: Only number or alphanumeric also?

Comment: Iterate over your list and check `type()` as int,  if found then break @sivabalasenna

Comment: only number, actually dotted decimal number

Comment: @Sanket - when i check the type of IP in the same list i found below output
146.89.4.32
<type 'str'>
It is considering as str not int

Comment: Please give at least one example of a list containing a "number" you want to search for.

Comment: You say "only number, actually dotted decimal number". That's not a number! That's a string with numbers and dots. Is your real question: "I want to find something that looks like an IP address."?

Comment: ['Neighbour', 'Information:', 'Chassis', 'type', ':', 'Mac', 'address', 'Address', ':', '146.89.4.32']
this is one of the example which has got IP ' 146.89.4.32'

Comment: @Matthias - Yes please

Comment: One way to do it would be to create an [`IPv4Address`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ip-addresses). If you don't get an [`AddressValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.AddressValueError) it's an IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expression.

[Please check this link for more info on regex !!!](http://pankajparashar.com/posts/python-regular-expressions/)

[More info how below regex works !!!](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%5C.%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%5C.%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%5C.%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D&test_string=146.89.4.32&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

```
import re
val = ['Neighbour', 'Information:', 'Chassis', 'type', ':', 'Mac', 'address', 'Address', ':', '146.89.4.32']

for v in val:
    temp = re.findall(r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}',v)
    if len(temp) !=0:
        print v
```

Comment: This will also match `999.999.999.999`, which cannot be an IP number.

Comment: The answer matches any combination, even if it is out of range @sivabalasenna ,  your IP address should in only `255.255.255.255` and should not cross `255`, How this answer achieve that

Comment: OP is taking output of some system command and want to extract IP address from that output. That's why I didn't check the validity  of IP address. IP validation check would be more useful if you are parsing file output or doing some input validation.